# iOS: how to prevent storyboard editor from moving my things around automatically?

Tags: ios, xcode

Occasionally I have a layout that's working perfectly well, but as soon as I open it in the storyboard editor in xcode, it does a bunch of changes automatically that break my layout.

I can literally start with a clean branch, open up my storyboard in xcode, and *without touching anything* it'll dump a bunch of changes to my storyboard XML.

Why does it do this, and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Please provide more details about what is breaking, perhaps screenshots would help here. Are you using auto-layout?